# Congruences and angles: geometric solution and analytical solution

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

**Problem**: Let $\triangle ABC$ be a right triangle in $A$. Let $O$ be the center of the square $BCDE$ constructed on the hypotenuse, on the side opposite the vertex $A$. Prove that $O$ is equidistant from the lines $AB$ and $AC$.

**Solution**:
[image]

We draw perpendiculars to $$ and $$ passing through $$, and call the points of $$ and $$ respectively the points of
intersection. Proving that $$ is equidistant from $$ and $$ is equivalent to proving that $\cong $.
Let $\gamma=A\hat C B$ and $\beta=A\hat BC=90^\circ-\gamma$. Consider the triangles $$ and $$ and prove
that they are congruent.

1. $ \cong $ because they are half of the diagonals $$ and $$ of the square, which are congruent.
2. $\hat{} \cong  \hat{}$ because right angles.
3. $\hat{C}K \cong  \hat{B}K$. In fact $\hat{C}K=\gamma+45°$ and $ \hat{B}K=180°-(\beta+45°)=180°-(90°-\gamma+45°)=\gamma+45°$. The right triangles $$ and $$ are therefore congruent by the hypotenuse-angle criterion, and consequently
   accordingly $\cong  $. We observe that the previous proof holds in the case where $\beta \geq \gamma$. In the event that $\beta < \gamma$ is valid
   $\hat{B}H=\beta+45°$ and $O\hat C K=180°-(\gamma+45°)=180° − (90° −  + 45°) =  + 45°.$

---

Question: **Is there possibly an analytical solution?**

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by an analytical solution. But an alternative approach would be to draw rotated copies of $\Delta ABC$ on each of the sides of $BCDE$ - this works as a proof without words.

Comment: @ChrisLewis Using the analytical geometry.

Comment: Seems like overkill - do you see what I mean about the three other copies of $\Delta ABC$?

Comment: @ChrisLewis No idea :-(

Comment: (but to answer your question, the easiest way would probably be to align the sides $AB$ and $AC$ with the $x$ and $y$ axes. Then you can show the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the centre of $BCDE$ are the same)

Comment: @ChrisLewis I have been thinking about it. You can see that my question has been edited a few times since this morning. I would be grateful if I could see from you a drawing with the solution.

Comment: I've added the proof without words version as an answer - hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the required analitical proof.

Take $A=(-r,0),B=(r,0),A(x_0,y_0),O=(0,-r)$

Line $AB: y_0x-(x_0+r)y+ry_0=0$

Line $AC: (x_0+r)x+y_0y-(x_0+r)r=0$

$$d(O;AB)=\dfrac{|y_0\cdot0+r(x_0+r)+ry_0|}{\sqrt{y_0^2+(x_0+r)^2}}$$

$$d(O;AC)=\dfrac{|(x_0+r)\cdot0-ry_0-r(x_0+r)|}{\sqrt{y_0^2+(x_0+r)^2}}$$

We are done.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a proof without words of the fact in the question:
[image]

(but I'll add a few words anyway; just notice that $O$ is also the centre of the square $AA'A''A'''$)